# what's the difference between the expressions 'there shall be an answer' and 'there will be an answer'?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, lyrics

There a lyrics, 'There will be an answer, let it be'. But I am curious about the change of the meaning of the sentence above when I substitute 'shall' for 'will'. Is there any difference made between them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! What song? Anything else you can tell us about the context?

Comment: “will” is for future declarative; “shall” is for future imperative.

Comment: I.e., as @StephenS stated, "will" means an answer can be found, but, "You shall answer," means you don't have the option to remain silent.

Comment: @Eddie Kal *Let It Be.* It's a song by one of these new "pop groups", M'lud.